# How to use Meta Tags with Symfony 2.0

Tags: symfony

I don't know how to add Meta Tags in all the pages of my website?

Comment: @Cerad Sorry I mean Meta Tags...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Correct, you can put your meta tags in the base layout of your site.
For more complex wishes you can put them into a block and if you want you can overwrite them in your specific templates.

For more information take a look at the Symfony2 documentation [Creating and using Templates](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/templating.html).

**Example:**

in your base template, e.g. base.html.twig in app/Resources/view

```
{% block meta_title %}Default meta title{% endblock %}
```

in your template:

```
{% extends '::base.html.twig' %}

{% block meta_title %}{{ page.title }}{% endblock %}
```

Comment: ,ok I agree but I need to use a dynamic content for each page of my website then I will create it using DB and I will put it inside block of meta tags,finally with Symfony 2.0 we don't have view.yml like perivious version of Symfony...tnks

Comment: ,ok will do the same thing but what you mean with "page.title"??

Comment: it's only an example for the title of the page.
You can also pass your metatags through the template.

Answer (score 7):

@F481,so I find a good solution,personnaly I do like that :

```
{% block meta %}
{% if (page.description) %}
    <meta name="description" content="{{ page.description }}">
{% endif %}

{% if (page.keywords) %}
    <meta name="keywords" content="{{ page.keywords }}">
{% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

And I store my keywords and description for each page in DB.

Answer (score 0):

Just put these meta tags in the base template of your site.

Comment: Cool! If you want something dynamic, you can use an embed controller, or template inheritance, like F481 says.