# How to add meta tag in symfony3?

Tags: php, symfony, twig, metadata, meta-tags

I want to add meta tags to my Symfony application.

[How to use Meta Tags with Symfony 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11492136/how-to-use-meta-tags-with-symfony-2-0)
[Twig change meta data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41055911/twig-change-meta-data)
https://symfony.com/doc/current/cmf/bundles/seo/twig.html.
These links can't help me find out the correct answer.

This is my code. My page where I need to add the tag. Say "about.html.twig"

```
{% extends 'AppBundle::layout.html.twig' %}

{% block body %} 
.
.
.
{% endblock %}
```

I wanted to know which one to use.

```
{% block meta %}{% endblock %}
```

(or)

```
{% block metadata %}{% endblock %}
```

(or)

```
{% block head %}
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**meta** or **metadata** or **head** are only the names. (not a statement)
 You can choose any name for this.

for example

base.html.twig

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
{% extends 'AppBundle::layout.html.twig' %}
  {% block title %}Title Website{% endblock %}
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />//////Repeat on all pages
    <meta http-equiv="content-language" content="fa,en">//////Repeat on all pages
  {% block metaTag %}
      <meta name="{{ description }}" content="Your description">
  {% endblock %}

{% block body %}

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: I have tried it. But it's not working. Do I need to add any bundles for it?

Comment: Do you have the error?   if this is not clear for  you plz read this Article https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/templating.html

Comment: There is no error. The meta tag is displayed as "<meta content="" name="description">" in the page source